# Can git refuse to checkin files whose new lines meet some criteria?

Tags: git, validation, diff

I am aware that you can configure git to pass files through some sort of validator before checking them in.

I want to apply validation only to *new* lines being checked in.

Here's a concrete made-up example. Let's say the project contains some Javascript files (with a `.js` extension) and some other files which are not Javascript and have distinct extensions. Suppose a policy is introduced: new code must use `let` instead of `var`, but existing code which uses `var` can keep it (because naively changing `var` to `let` might breaks stuff).

Suppose we have `example.js` already in the repository, before the policy introduction, which contains the following:

```
function f (arg)
{
    var foo = arg+1;
    other_func (foo);
}
```

After the policy change, we modify this file to introduce a new feature;

```
function f (arg)
{
    var foo = arg+1;
    var bar = arg-1;
    other_func (foo, bar);
}
```

The two new lines are

```
    var bar = arg-1;
    other_func (foo, bar);
```

Suppose I have a script `validate-js.sh` which reads an individual line of Javascript from standard input and exits with status 0 if the input conforms to the policy and 1 otherwise.

Piping the above two lines into `validate-js.sh` will yield an exit code of 1 for the first line because `bar` is declared as `var` instead of `let`, and 0 for the second line because no variables are declared. However, even though `foo` was declared as `var`, *it is already in the repository* and hence we don't subject that line of code to the same validation.

Clearly, in general, the validation script will need access to the whole file, not just the individual lines with no context.

The requirement is that, where validation fails, git aborts the checkin and reports a message along the lines of

```
Validation of example.js failed on line 4
```

It's not particularly important how git and the validation script communicate. For example, if git called the script with filenames of the old and new version as arguments, and a list of line numbers in the new file which deserve attention, that would be fine. Whatever works as long as validation is not applied to previously-checked-in code on a line-by-line basis. It needs to work on a generic Unix/Linux system, so assume bash, perl etc are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is create a `git pre-commit hook`.

Your script would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

list_of_new_files=($(git diff --name-only --cached))
for file in "${list_of_files[@]}"; do
  # Run you validation code here
  # Print the errors for each file
  # Store if validation for any file failed in $validated
done

exit $validated
```

As long as the `pre-commit` hook exists with a non-zero status code, git will refuse the commit.

Here's [an example](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#Client-Side-Hooks) from the official docs.

You then need to install this git pre-commit hook into each user/developer's repository manually or as part of the contributing guidelines. You can have an identical check on the server side as well, but it's preferable to catch it early so developers can fix what they need.

To install the hook, you must name the executable `pre-commit`, make it executable (`chmod +x`) and copy it into `.git/hooks`.

Comment: I wish I could  upvote you more than once. Nice answer.

Comment: As a complement: if you really want to _enforce_ this policy, you need to do the check on the server (typically in the `pre-receive` hook), or people could disable (or forget) the `pre-commit` hook. Ideally, you can have both (the `pre-commit` since it's convenient, and the `pre-receive` since it is more reliable).

Comment: When I include the --cached flag, git diff produces no output.

Comment: @spraff, did you run a git add before doing a git commit?

Comment: @spraff, you need to `git add` the files first. The check is run when you do a `git commit`. The `git commit` will fail, if your `pre-commit` hook fails. That's how a `pre-commit` hook works.

Comment: Thanks, you're being very helpful. Can you please extend your answer to show how the validation code would know which lines in a given file are new?

Comment: @spraff it was my understanding that you already had something that could understand and validate diff files, which is why I left it out. I'll add that in.